# PowerShell Layered Script - Passing error codes for dependencies

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have started using a monitoring system called Cronitor that wraps scheduled task executions in their EXE.

Cronitor.exe exec (UID for monitor) "Path to script/executable".

Adding to that, I am working on synchronizing some of our scheduled tasks that are dependent on each other.

The problem I have is that because the executable wraps scripts/programs/tasks, the error code returned to Windows task scheduler is always 0 because it's not passed in their exe.

My work around is to layer powershell scripts (which I am not super proficient in yet).

So Action 1 calls "StartAction.ps1"

Inside that ps1 script,

Start-Process "Path to cronitor" -ArgumentList "Crontior arguments and path to ps1 that initiates exe for action 1" -Wait
Start-Process "Path to cronitor" -ArgumentList "Crontior arguments and path to ps1 that initiates exe for action 2"

The issue I am running into is the same for trying to stop the scheduled task if the process fails in action 1. I need to pass the error code (1) up through a pipeline to the initiating script so it knows to stop.

Is that even possible, or are there other solutions I am missing?

Comment: To clarify, you do not want the second `Start-Process` to execute if the first produced an error?

Comment: That is correct. The second program is (should be) dependent upon the first.

Comment: If you tagged `-ErrorAction "Stop"` to the end of `Start-Process`, it should bomb out if anything is fed to the error output stream.

Comment: Thank you @codaamok, I'll try that and update here once I find a solution.